# Does using one buffer for vertices, uvs and normals in OpenGL perform better than using three?

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer

I find cleaner and easier to work with keeping those elements in separate buffers, but I wanted to know if it performs better having them all in one big buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are talking about Structure of Arrays or Array of Structures and it's efficiency. In most cases Array of Structures is more efficient because it will make better use of processor cache, but this assumes that you will access the data in order they are in memory.

But if you some data is refreshed at different rate than the other one it will benefit to have them in different buffers, that way you can update only the data you need to update.

Answer (score 6):

The advantage of using multiple buffers is that you can easily disable one for some special rendering (depth-only for example doesn't need normals nor texture coordinates).

However, storing all your attributes interleaved in one single array provide a better cache locality when rendering.

Answer (score 3):

According the [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_more),

> you don't lose much performance if you use separate VBOs. It would be
>   on the order of 5% but your testing might show otherwise.

I don't know if this statement is only for dynamic data, but in my engine I use separate VBO.